# How to find a set of answers for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So I have two planes $H_1(a_1,b_1)$ and $H_2 (a_2,b_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with

$a_1$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-2 \\
3 
\end{bmatrix}$,
$b_1 = 4$, 
$a_2$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
-3 
\end{bmatrix}$,
$b_2=-2$

where $H(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} | a^Tx = b\}$.

Now, I have to find the set $M = H(a_1,b_1) \cap H(a_2,b_2)$.

I started but can't get far really:

$a_1^Tx = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &-2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} x = 4$ with $x \in \mathbb{R^3}.$

How do i find this set of $x$? And similarly, find $H(a_2,b_2)$ and do the intersection...

Comment: The two planes will intersect in a line. What is the direction of this line in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: @Paul $a_1 \wedge a_2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in M$, then $a_1^Tx=b_1$ and $a_2^Tx=b_2$. But we can put these together into the single matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1^T \\ a_2^T\end{bmatrix} x = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Does this resemble anything you know what to do with?

Comment: not exactly, also how come there is this 3rd x in the equation?

Comment: @Leonardo Because I made a typesetting mistake. :-D What about now? And if not, what if you put in the numbers?

Comment: well honestly no, thats basically another option of writing of what I already had written. My problem lies with x. how is it interpreted here? because obviously its not a scalar, like 1x1 matrix, because $a_1^T$ is 1x3 matrix and x needs to be 3xn matrix the multiplication to be possible. so I imagine its exactly 3x1 matrix since it is from $\mathbb{R^3}$ ?

Comment: @Leonardo It is indeed just a rewrite, but I'd hoped you'd see that highlighted that this was just a linear system of equations. And you are correct, $x$ is a $3\times 1$ vector; as you noted, that is made clear by $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Leonardo Are you familiar with linear systems of the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$? Because that's precisely what you have.

Comment: @Leonardo If $a$ and $x$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, then $a^Tx = a\cdot x$.